# Absence of an ouput from the thread running in the wrapper class scoped_thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

If to run this program using www.ideone.com

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

class scoped_thread
{
private:
    std::thread t;

public:
    explicit scoped_thread( std::thread t ) : t( std::move( t ) )
    {
        if ( not this->t.joinable() )
        {
            throw std::logic_error( "No thread" );
        }
    }

    ~scoped_thread()
    {
        t.join();
    }

    scoped_thread( const scoped_thread & ) = delete;
    scoped_thread & operator =( const scoped_thread & ) = delete;
};

void h()
{
    std::cout << "h() is running\n";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++ );
    std::cout << "exiting h()\n";
}

void f()
{
    scoped_thread t( std::thread( h ) );
}

int main() 
{
    f();

    std::thread t( h );
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

then the output is

```
h() is running
exiting h()
```

that corresponds to the thread `t` launced in main.

However a simialr output from the thread launched using the class `scoped_thread` is absent. Why?

Comment: `scoped_thread t{ std::thread( h ) };` works, otherwise it complains that `'scoped_thread t(std::thread)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/5470596):

```
scoped_thread t( std::thread( h ) );
```

This defines a function `t` taking an `std::thread` named `h` and returning a `scopted_thread`. To actually declare the object, declare instead:

```
scoped_thread t{ std::thread(h) };
```